# orientation of an application doesn't get perfect

Tags: android, orientation

when I change the orientation of emulator the logo and menu icon don't move to the both end of the screen but it shows in the middle.

this is my code.

`

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivmainlogo"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/alfadesign1"
    />

     <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivmainmenu"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/menu1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

here is the image of the result which get.
[image]

please help me in this code, 
thank you.

Comment: do you have any landscape layout..???

Comment: see my post i have edited it...

Comment: you need to put layout-land  folder and put same file with landscape orientation

Comment: can you give the code for that?

Comment: where should I put that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a lot of experimentation here is the solution.Try this code out.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/ivmainlogo"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:src="@drawable/alfadesign1"
/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="right">

 <ImageView 
android:id="@+id/ivmainmenu"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:src="@drawable/menu1"
/>

 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making the gravity of linearLyout "center".

Make individual gravity of both Imageview to left and right respectively.

```
 <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivmainlogo"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/alfadesign1"
    />

     <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivmainmenu"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/menu1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"/>
```

Comment: have you removed gravity of linearlayout?

Comment: ya i have removed it also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="70dp"
 android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/ivmainlogo"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:src="@drawable/alfadesign1"
/>

 <ImageView 
android:id="@+id/ivmainmenu"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:src="@drawable/menu1"
android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
android:gravity="right"/>
```